# Using zip() with a Maybe that may not emit a value

Tags: android, observable, rx-java2

I'm trying to execute two `Maybe` at once and call a specific method once both are done. This works if both Observables return a value but in certain cases one might not emit an item thus calling only `doOnComplete` and not `doOnSuccess`. So if one of those Maybes' doesn't call `doOnSuccess` the `zip()` block isn't executed. I'm wondering how to handle such a scenario?

Following my code (stripped down to the essential part):

```
private void fetchData(){
    Maybe<Integer> maybeOne = getId(); // may return Maybe.empty()
    Maybe<List<String>> maybeTwo = getList();
    Maybe.zip(maybeOne, maybeTwo, (id, list) -> {
        initView(id, list); // only called if values have been emitted
        return true;
    }).subscribe();
}
```

I would expect that the zip() block is always called but with null values in case the Maybe didn't call `onSuccess`. This isn't the case so can I handle such a scenario?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [materialize](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/materialize-dematerialize.html) operator. It basically transforms the serial invocation into object (wrapped inside a `Notification` object).

```
Observable.zip(maybeOne.toObservable().materialize(),
                maybeTwo.toObservable().materialize(), (id, list) -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "zip completed");
                    return true;
                }).subscribe();
```

Now your `zip` will always "finish", but your real data can be retrieved using:

```
id.getValue()
```

And if your maybe is `Maybe.empty()` then it will not return the value, but null.

Comment: Excellent, this feels much more clean than explicitly wrapping all the objects in `Optional<T>` or creating "empty" instances to compare with, which are the other two solutions I've seen for this problem. It feels a little verbose that you have to call `toObservable().materialize()` on every input stream, but I guess if you do this in many places you can write your own `zipAlways(Maybe, Maybe, NullableParamFunction)`.

Comment: I got a warning saying `materialize` is marked unstable.